# javafx deleting contents of an accordion pane

Tags: javafx

I have an accordion pane which contains three titled panes. I wish to delete these in the java program, however the Accordion object doesn't seem to have a clear or remove method to do this.

I have tried some ways to get around this such as the following:

```
    if (!measureAccordion.getChildrenUnmodifiable().isEmpty()) {
        ObservableList<javafx.scene.Node> accordionContent = measureAccordion.getChildrenUnmodifiable();
        accordionContent.clear();
        }
```

But this raised an UnsupportedOperationException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check here [accordion in javaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Accordion.html#getPanes--) , you will see that the accordion object has a method, getPanes(), which returns an ObservableList of TitledPane. The ObservableList has a lot of methods that you could use such as removeAll. You can see here [the documentation for ObservableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html).

Comment: 'removeAll' method doesn't work in JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

`Accordion` is a control that can contain only `TitledPane` components. So if you want to modify content of `Accordion` then use [Accordion#getPanes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Accordion.html#getPanes--) method.